# Unroutable address when sending email with exim from vm1 to vm2

Tags: email-server, exim

I am trying to send emails from virtual machine 1 to virtual machine 2 but I get the error `Unroutable address` and more specifically `dnslookup_relay_to_domains router declined for user@lab1`

Looking at exim documentation I found that `This option specifies a text message that is used when an address cannot be routed because Exim has run out of routers. The default message is “Unrouteable address”`, but still I don't understand how to fix this.

Virtual machine 1 hostname is `lab1` and ip address is `10.0.2.5`

Virtual machine 2 hostname is `lab2` and ip address is `10.0.2.6`

Here are the settings in update-exim4.cong.conf:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='lab2; localhost'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='lab1'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

Simulating with `exim -bhc` sending and email to 10.0.2.5 I got:

```
>>> routing user@lab1
>>> expansion of "${if exists{/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}{partial-lsearch;/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}fail}" forced failure: assume not in this list
>>> lab1 in "! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains"? yes (matched "+relay_to_domains" - cached)
>>> R: dnslookup_relay_to_domains for user@lab1
>>> calling dnslookup_relay_to_domains router
>>> dnslookup_relay_to_domains router declined for user@lab1
>>> "more" is false: skipping remaining routers
>>> no more routers
>>> ----------- end verify ------------
>>> require: condition test failed in ACL "acl_check_rcpt"
>>> end of ACL "acl_check_rcpt": not OK
550 Unrouteable address
LOG: H=(mail) [10.0.2.6] F=<user@lab2> rejected RCPT user@lab1: Unrouteable address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying many things and got a bit messed up with the configuration. Finally sorted it out and used the configuration for "mail sent by smarthost". I did the following changed to the configuration:

`dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'` changed to `dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'`

`dc_relay_domains='lab1'` changed to `dc_relay_domains=''`

`dc_smarthost=''` changed to `dc_smarthost='lab1'`